# tikzexternalize and xespotcolor

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, tikz-external

With package `xespotcolor`, I can define and use spot colors with `XeLaTeX`. This works, even together with `tikz`.

I am, however, having trouble when I try to use spot colors in *externalized* tikz pictures. The `pdf` file produced for the picture is corrupt, and, as a consequence, the final pdf file after including the picture (second tex run) as well.

I have tracked down the problem to a color space definition being missing in the picture pdf. There should be code as follows in the pdf

```
  /ColorSpace <<
    /PANTONE285C [
      /Separation
      /PANTONE#20285#20C
      /DeviceCMYK
      632 0 R
    ]
  >>
```

but there isn't. It seems that `tikzexternalize` skips the output generated by `xespotcolor` when generating the picture pdf.

Is there any way to force `tikzexternalize` not to skip something when generating the picture pdf? Or to include particular code in every picture pdf? I need something like a hook.

Minimum non-working example -- compiling it by `xelatex --shell-escape [filename]` produces a corrupt figure pdf, where the color space definition is missing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\RequirePackage[xcolor]{xespotcolor}
\NewSpotColorSpace{PANTONE}
\AddSpotColor{PANTONE}{PANTONE285C}{PANTONE\SpotSpace 285\SpotSpace C} {1 .45 0 0.19}
\SetPageColorSpace{PANTONE}
\definecolor{myblue}{spotcolor}{PANTONE285C,1.0}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [myblue] (0,0) -- (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: looks ok to me. The colorspace is there. Which tex system are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem with texlive 2019.

But in texlive 2020 and a new LaTeX 2020-10-01 and the new everypage which uses the new LaTeX hooks, the pdf is fine and the color space is there.

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into that. Upgrading to texlive 2020 indeed solves the problem!